Speed of Light Which Varies With Direction in 1+1 Dimensional Spacetime
Suppose there are two frames $(t,x),(t',x')$ in $1+1$ dimensional spacetime, with coinciding origins at $t=t'=0$. Furthermore, suppose that unprimed frame observes the prime frame moving at velocity $v.$ However, suppose the speed of light varies directionally, in that the speed of light in the positive direction, $c_+,$ is not equal to the speed of light in the negative direction, $c_-.$ How would this change the usual
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$
$$x'=\gamma(x-vt)?$$

It is a bit vague, the answer might depend on how the speed of light varies in the two directions. It is also not mainstream physics

This is a pretty straightforward calculation.  Where are you stuck?

@Damian:  It seems to me to be neither vague nor non-mainstream.  I wouldn't hesitate to pose it as a homework problem.   But I do think it should be closed as homework-like, pending more information from the OP as to what the sticking point is.

@WillO Is it as simple as replacing c with $c_\pm$ in accordance with the sign of $v$? (Also adjusting $\gamma$ accordingly?) If so, I’ll delete the question.

@WillO When we express the formula as a Lorentz matrix acting on a Minkowski vector, what even are the vectors? Convention in the usual problem would say $(ct,x),$ so it is not obvious how we would alter this in the $c_\pm$ case.

The theory of relativity traditionally uses a synchronization convention where the one way speed of light (OWSOL) is $c$. That convention was useful, but was recognized as a convention from the beginning. So not long after relativity was developed, alternative conventions were also investigated.
The most famous early work on this topic was Reichenbach. But a few decades later his work was put into a more convenient form (in my opinion) by Anderson (Anderson, Vetharaniam, and Stedman. “Conventionality of synchronisation, gauge dependence and test theories of relativity”. Physics Reports. 295 1998. 93-180).
Anderson (eq 23 and 24) uses the coordinates $$\tilde t = t- \mathbf \kappa \cdot \mathbf{x}/c$$$$\tilde{ \mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{x}$$ so that the OWSOL in the $\hat{\mathbf n}$ direction is $$c(\hat{\mathbf n})=\frac{c \ \hat{\mathbf n}}{1-\mathbf \kappa \cdot \hat{\mathbf n}}$$ and other velocities are $$\tilde{\mathbf v} = \frac{\mathbf v}{1-\mathbf \kappa \cdot \mathbf v/c} $$ In these expressions a tilde indicates a quantity in the coordinate system with an anisotropic OWSOL and the absence of a tilde indicates a quantity in the standard Einstein coordinate system. The exceptions are $\mathbf \kappa$ which is the vector describing the OWSOL, as indicated above, and $c$ which is the two-way SOL.
In these coordinates the Lorentz transform becomes (eq 39 and 40) quite a mess: $$d\tilde t' = \tilde \gamma \left[ 1+ \mathbf \kappa \cdot \tilde{\mathbf v}/c-\mathbf \kappa' \cdot \tilde{\mathbf v}'/c \right] d\tilde t - \left(\mathbf \kappa ' + \tilde{\gamma} \tilde{\mathbf v}'/c\right)\cdot d\tilde{x}/c -\left[ \tilde{\gamma}\left( 1+\mathbf \kappa \cdot \tilde{\mathbf v}/c \right)-1 \right] \frac{\mathbf \kappa'\cdot\tilde{\mathbf v}}{\tilde{\mathbf v}^2 c}\tilde{\mathbf v}\cdot d\tilde{\mathbf x}+\tilde{\gamma} \mathbf\kappa \cdot \tilde{\mathbf v}\left( \mathbf\kappa \cdot d\tilde{\mathbf x} \right)/c^2$$$$ d\tilde{\mathbf x}'=-\tilde{\gamma} \tilde{\mathbf v} \ d\tilde{t} + d\tilde{\mathbf x} + \left[ \tilde{\gamma}\left( 1 + \mathbf\kappa \cdot \tilde{\mathbf v}/c \right) -1 \right] \frac{\tilde{\mathbf v} \cdot d\mathbf x}{\tilde{\mathbf v}^2}\tilde{\mathbf v}-\tilde{\gamma} \tilde{\mathbf v} \left( \mathbf \kappa \cdot d\tilde{\mathbf x} \right)/c$$ where $\tilde{\gamma} = \gamma \left( 1 - \mathbf{\kappa} \cdot \mathbf{v} / c \right)$
As you can see, it is little wonder why this anisotropic OWSOL convention is never used except to answer questions about the OWSOL on internet forums.

Perfect! Thank you so much, I figured it wasn’t as simple as I initially thought!

I just realized that the formula by Anderson seems to have a typo, as taking $\kappa=\kappa'=0$ does not yield the original transformation. Namely, the time equation yields $t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c}\right),$ missing a factor of c in the denominator of the $x$ term.

I think I fixed it. Looking at the dimensions there appeared to be two missing factors of $c$.

What a deep typo haha, seems it got into the Wikipedia page.

Thanks to @Dale, I used the general formula for a one way speed of light, with the additional assumptions of 1 spatial dimension and constant scalar synchrony $\kappa$ (the assumptions of the original question), to obtain the following formulae:
$$t'=\gamma\left[\left(1-\frac{2\kappa v}{c}\right)t-\left(\frac{v}{c^2}+\frac{\kappa}{c}\left(1-\frac{2\kappa v}{c}\right)\right)x\right]$$
$$x'=\gamma(x-vt).$$
As we can see, it strictly takes on the form of a correction in the time term, so we can express:
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}-\xi\right),$$
$$x'=\gamma(x-vt),$$
where this correction term in terms of $c_\pm$ is
$$\xi=\frac{c_+-c_-}{c_+c_-}vt+\frac{c_+-c_-}{2c_+c_-}\left(1-\frac{c_+-c_-}{c_+c_-}v\right)x.$$
It is also of note that this forces
$$c=\frac{2c_+c_-}{c_++c_-},\kappa=\frac{c_+-c_-}{c_++c_-}.$$

@Dale The formula didn't turn out too ugly! Thank you for your help!
